# Which type is BLOB?

Tags: java, db2, blob

I have about 100,000 BLOBs in my database and have to work with them. All is ok when someone tells me which type of BLOB I must deal with. But there will be situations when I will not know which type is it. So how can I find out which type my BLOB is?

Last time I handled BLOB I get specific info about it, it was zipped file. So I did this..

```
try {
   byte[] str = this.jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT SAVEDATA FROM JDBEVPP1.TEVP005 WHERE GFNR = 357302", byte[].class);    // pakira BLOB u byte array
   ByteArrayInputStream bys = new ByteArrayInputStream(str);
   GZIPInputStream gzip = new GZIPInputStream(bys);
   //...etc...
}
```

How can I find out which type BLOB is using Java code?

Comment: The usual way to identify a binary file of some type is to have some "magic numbers" at the beginning of the file that you can use to identify the type.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Magic_numbers_in_files and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format#Magic_number

Comment: In general, you can't identify what kind of object it is. It is after all just a "binary large object". Just like you can't know if the byte `01000001` represents an ASCII `A`, the integer 65, some compressed/encrypted value, or if it has another meaning within some context.

Comment: Store metadata...

Comment: Take a look at this [project on Github](https://github.com/j256/simplemagic)

Comment: By reading the detailed specs of the database design.  Absent that, by trying to locate the original author of the system and hoping he still remembers.  Absent that, by trying to locate other code that uses the same BLOB and kind of re-engineering the spec from there.  In most shops you will have to go all the way to the third step alas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final answer to this question would be the comment of Robert Harvey:

"The usual way to identify a binary file of some type is to have some "magic numbers" at the beginning of the file that you can use to identify the type. See en.wikipedia.org/wiki/… and en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format#Magic_number"

And also comment of Erwin Smout:

"By reading the detailed specs of the database design. Absent that, by trying to locate the original author of the system and hoping he still remembers. Absent that, by trying to locate other code that uses the same BLOB and kind of re-engineering the spec from there. In most shops you will have to go all the way to the third step alas. "